# Ordering a list

Tags: python, list, sorting

I have a list like this,

```
M=[[75], [95, 64], [17, 47, 82], [18, 35, 87, 10], [20, 4, 82, 47, 65], [19, 
1, 23, 75, 3, 34], [88, 2, 77, 73, 7, 63, 67], [99, 65, 4, 28, 6, 16, 70, 
92], [41, 41, 26, 56, 83, 40, 80, 70, 33], [41, 48, 72, 33, 47, 32, 37, 16, 
94, 29], [53, 71, 44, 65, 25, 43, 91, 52, 97, 51, 14], [70, 11, 33, 28, 77, 
73, 17, 78, 39, 68, 17, 57], [91, 71, 52, 38, 17, 14, 91, 43, 58, 50, 27, 
29, 48], [63, 66, 4, 68, 89, 53, 67, 30, 73, 16, 69, 87, 40, 31], [4, 62, 
98, 27, 23, 9, 70, 98, 73, 93, 38, 53, 60, 4, 23]]
```

and I would like to sort it by the largest number on the "zero" position for each element in the list for example,

```
M=[[75], [95, 64], [82, 47, 17], [87, 35, 18, 10].....]
```

I tried to use a key but it didnt work well also I didnt know why it didnt work well..Here the key

```
def Len(elem):
    for i in range(16):
        y=len(K[i])
        return elem[y-1]
y=sorted(K,key=Len)
print(y)
```

Maybe I just didnt understand the key function.
Thanks

Comment: Do you also want to preserve the ordering of individual lists?

Comment: does "sort by the largest" mean you want the large numbers at the front or at the end?

Comment: You should read the [Sorting HOWTO](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html#sortinghowto) in the docs to understand how key functions work. The key function should be looking at the element, not the entire list.

Comment: Also, putting an unconditional `return` inside a loop like that defeats the purpose of looping. You may want to read about [functions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#defining-functions) in the tutorial if it's not obvious to you why that is.

Comment: Look at my sample code I want it like that

Comment: I ll look them thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use `sorted` (or `list.sort`) without a `key`. They already sort lexicographically.

```
>>> sorted(M, reverse=True)
[[99, 65, 4, 28, 6, 16, 70, 92], [95, 64], [91, 71, 52, 38, 17, 14, 91, 43, 58, 50, 27, 29, 48], [88, 2, 77, 73, 7, 63, 67], [75], [70, 11, 33, 28, 77, 73, 17, 78, 39, 68, 17, 57], [63, 66, 4, 68, 89, 53, 67, 30, 73, 16, 69, 87, 40, 31], [53, 71, 44, 65, 25, 43, 91, 52, 97, 51, 14], [41, 48, 72, 33, 47, 32, 37, 16, 94, 29], [41, 41, 26, 56, 83, 40, 80, 70, 33], [20, 4, 82, 47, 65], [19, 1, 23, 75, 3, 34], [18, 35, 87, 10], [17, 47, 82], [4, 62, 98, 27, 23, 9, 70, 98, 73, 93, 38, 53, 60, 4, 23]]
```

edit:

Sorting the lists individually:

```
>>> [sorted(sublist, reverse=True) for sublist in M]
[[75], [95, 64], [82, 47, 17], [87, 35, 18, 10], [82, 65, 47, 20, 4], [75, 34, 23, 19, 3, 1], [88, 77, 73, 67, 63, 7, 2], [99, 92, 70, 65, 28, 16, 6, 4], [83, 80, 70, 56, 41, 41, 40, 33, 26], [94, 72, 48, 47, 41, 37, 33, 32, 29, 16], [97, 91, 71, 65, 53, 52, 51, 44, 43, 25, 14], [78, 77, 73, 70, 68, 57, 39, 33, 28, 17, 17, 11], [91, 91, 71, 58, 52, 50, 48, 43, 38, 29, 27, 17, 14], [89, 87, 73, 69, 68, 67, 66, 63, 53, 40, 31, 30, 16, 4], [98, 98, 93, 73, 70, 62, 60, 53, 38, 27, 23, 23, 9, 4, 4]]
```

Comment: Wait I read it wrong it doesnt work like that. I want to display the largest number for each array in the descending form.For example in your response the last element is [4, 62, 98, 27, 23, 9, 70, 98, 73, 93, 38, 53, 60, 4, 23] but I need something like [98,98,93,...etc] I mean for each element in the list should be ordered.

Comment: @ArthurMorgan so in other words, you want to sort each list in your list of lists?

Comment: well yes I want it like that.

Comment: @ArthurMorgan no problem, please select one of the answers as accepted to indicate that the problem is solved.

Answer (score 1):

Try operator itemgetter function as key.
Like this:
    
`from operator import itemgetter
sorted(K,key=itemgetter(0))`

Comment: @Julien it is actually different behavior than lexicographic sort. The OP is not clear on whether that matters or not.

Comment: actually just the larger number on the zero element also fine by me

Comment: I ll try yours now

Answer (score 0):

try using index of each element :

```
for i in M:
    M[M.index(i)]=sorted(i,reverse=True)
```